# Zooming in on pixel art in Cocos2D causes blur- iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, scale, blur, ccsprite

When a CCSprite of mine, which uses a 16x16 image, is scaled up, there is a lot of blurring.

This image is pixel art, and therefore meant to be pixelated, but not blurred.

I've tried running the method `setAntiAliasTexParameters` on the texture of the sprite, but it doesn't change anything.

Here is the code: (mainSprite is CCSprite and slide1 is CCTexture2D)

```
slide1 = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slide1.png"]];
[slide1 setAntiAliasTexParameters];

[mainSprite setTexture:slide1];
```

Thank you, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this instead:

```
[slide1 setAliasTexParameters];
```

this will tell your sprite not to anti-alias, preserving the pixelated look

(using cocos2d v2.0 -- not sure if this works in previous versions)

Answer (score 2):

In general it is better to use a higher resolution image and SCALE DOWN. For example if your going to use an image that when it is as large as it is going to get will be 32x32. Then use a 32x32 image and when you need it at your 16x16 resolution, scale it down to that.

Answer (score 1):

Your image is too small to scale up..simple as that. If you don't want blur make a bigger image and use that.

It's recommended to use a 1:1 scale image when you do something (unless it's a scalable image, like a single color..or 2 colors, or a line, or something like that). If you have an icon and you want to scale it up..forget it..just make a bigger icon and scale down if necessary.

Comment: The image is simple pixel art, but when scaled up isn't in single pixels but instead they're blurred together

Comment: then your problem is ccBlendFunc .Try doing something like : `[yoursprite setBlendFunc: (ccBlendFunc){GL_ONE,GL_ZERO}]`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it seems to make no difference.

Comment: well i don't know anything about open gl blend functions and/or how they work, but that **is** your problem...look into it